# How to represent a part of a string as an image in HTML?

Tags: python-3.x, html, jinja2

I am working on a personal project in which I am using Magic the Gathering's API to search through their card databases and display them on my website. One of the problems I have encountered is that an argument of the card object that is stored in the database is displayed as {G},{R},{B},{U},{W} etc. but I want it to be displayed as one of the many images found here:

https://media-dominaria.cursecdn.com/attachments/132/91/635465459096129102.png

Considering that the argument is a string, I don't know how to replace the content of the string that is inside the curly brackets with a html image element and have it display properly in the browser.

For example:

mana_cost= "{G}{W}"

I would like to be able to show "{G}" as: 
http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130604114032/mtg/images/f/f7/Mana_G.png

and "{W}" as:

https://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/8/88760/2277116-white_mana.png

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RegEx on the client side and replace with the image before showing in the browser.

```
let strToReplace = '{G}';

strToReplace = strToReplace.replace(/{G}/, '<img src="http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130604114032/mtg/images/f/f7/Mana_G.png">');
```

I would download the image and put it on a local folder so you can replace for something like:

`strToReplace = strToReplace.replace(/{G}/, '<img src="/images/Mana_G.png">');`

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/649y20s3/